# Flutter login control in splash screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a small login application. When entering the application, I want to inquire whether the user has a token code or not on the splash screen. How can do this? thank you for help.

main.dart file

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

My splash screen.
I want to know if the user has a token or not

```
    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loginControl();
  }

  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<bool> loginControl() async {
    bool status = AuthController.isLoginUser() as bool;
    print(status);
    if (status) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen()));
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('welcome my app'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my auth controller like this;

```
class AuthController {
  static Future<bool> isLoginUser() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
    if (token == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi. I don't really understand the question, it looks like you have a good solution. Could you explain a bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isLoginUser` is actually returning a `Future<bool>` means that it returns a `Future` that will later resolve to a `bool` value.

So, when you use it like this in your `loginControl`,

```
bool status = AuthController.isLoginUser() as bool;
```

`AuthController.isLoginUser()` return `Future<bool>` and it can't be directly converted to a `bool` using `as bool`.

Instead you should `await` that Future to resolve, like this.

```
bool status = await AuthController.isLoginUser(); // This will work.
```

Now, your code will pause at this line, until it gets a return value from `isLoginUser` and then resume to next line with `status` being an actual `bool` value. i.e., `true` or `false`.

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Hope my explanation was adequate as well.